# How can I initialize wx.Font objects before the wx.App is created?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

My application has a module called `gui_constants` that contains the definitions of all of the fonts and colors used by my application. For example, `gui_constants.py` might contain a line like

```
heading_font = wx.Font(12, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, face='LucidaGrande')
```

and another file might say

```
heading_label = wx.StaticText(self, label='Lorem Ipsum')
heading_label.SetFont(gui_constants.heading_font)
```

The problem I’m having is that my `gui_constants` module is being imported before the `wx.App` is created, which leads to an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from new_gui_app import NewGuiApp
  File ".../application/new_gui_app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from views import MainWindow
  File ".../application/views/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from banner import Banner
  File ".../application/views/banner.py", line 3, in <module>
    import gui_constants
  File ".../application/gui_constants.py", line 63, in <module>
    heading_font = wx.Font(12, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, face='LucidaGrande')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.9.5-osx_cocoa/wx/_gdi.py", line 2156, in __init__
    _gdi_.Font_swiginit(self,_gdi_.new_Font(*args, **kwargs))
wx._core.PyNoAppError: The wx.App object must be created first!
```

Can anyone suggest a way to keep these “constant” declarations factored out into a single module, while also preventing them from being initialized before the `wx.App` is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I ended up using was to add an `initialize` method to my `gui_constants` module:

```
def initialize():
    global heading_font
    heading_font = wx.Font(12, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, face='LucidaGrande')
```

This approach requires that the user call this method before they use any of the constants defined in `gui_constants`, but after the `App` has been created. (Calling `initialize` before the `App` is ready results in a PyNoAppError, as in my question, and calling it too late gives an AttributeError when someone tries to access one of the not-yet-defined fonts.) The timing is not as tricky as I thought it would be, though; I call `initialize` at the beginning of my `App` subclass’s `OnInit` method and that seems to work fine.

There were three other options mentioned (by Mike Driscoll and by VZ):

1. **Store the font information in a tuple and pass this tuple to a `create_font` function each time a font is needed.** For my taste this is too heavy; all users of the constants module need to know about the font-creation function, which should be a private implementation detail. It also adds a small amount of syntactic overhead all over the place.
2. **Use `eval`.** The dangers of `eval` are well-known, and my personal policy is not to use it unless there’s no other way.
3. **Store the fonts as `FontInfo` objects and convert them to `Font` objects later.** This could be done by passing the `FontInfo` to some constructor each time we want to use that font, as in option (1), or by constructing the `Font` objects en masse, as I’m doing in my eventual solution. Using the former approach has the same objections I mentioned for item (1). Using the latter approach is basically what I’m doing, but with an extra layer of indirection.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options. One really easy way to do it is to change the constants into tuples instead of wx.Font objects:

```
heading_font = (12, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, 'LucidaGrande')
```

Then when you import it, you can do something like this:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def create_font(data):
    """"""
    size, family, style, weight, face = data
    font = wx.Font(size, family, style, weight, face=face)
    return font


########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        print type(gui_constants.heading_font)
        print create_font(gui_constants.heading_font)
```

An alternative you could try is using Python's **eval**. If you did it this way, you would want to store your constants as strings, like this:

```
heading_font = "wx.Font(12, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, face='LucidaGrande')"
```

Then in your wxPython code, you'd do something like this:

```
########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        print type(eval(gui_constants.heading_font))
```

Note that eval has a small danger in that if the user is allowed to modify the gui_constants file, they could insert malicious code. If they cannot modify it, then there isn't much of a danger at all.

Comment: The tuple solution is the best one, I'd just add that in 3.0 you have `wxFontInfo` which is a simple tuple-like class which also can be created before the GUI is initialized and from which `wxFont` can be created directly.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too, but I wanted to give a couple of options.